# java Put an object array into an object array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello Everybody sorry in advance for my bad wording of the question. I am only allowed 4 classes, Movie,Moviedatabase,Playlist and Interface. In interface the method playlist,

1.I am trying to store an object array into an object array and am not every sure how to do so. Since the playlist array can be resized.

2.Whenever I try to print my results using list method in Moviedatabase I just get blank lines. Confused as to why

edit.This is a school assessment and nowhere near finished so.. Im guessing there will be a fair amount of errors here and there.

```
public class Interface
{
//create a scanner
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
static MovieDatabase md = new MovieDatabase(); 
static Playlist p = new Playlist();
private int total = 0;
private Playlist[] playlistArray = [total];
private Playlist[] playlist;

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int choice = 0;


    while(choice != 15)
    {   
        showSelection();
        choice = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        switch(choice) 
        {

            case 1: addMovie();  
                    break;

            case 2: md.list(1,"",0);
                    break;

            case 3: System.out.println("What is the name of the movie you wish to delete?");
                    String name = input.nextLine();
                    md.delete(name);
                    break;

            case 4: editMovie();
                    break;

            case 5: directorList();
                    break;

            case 6: durationList();
                    break;

            case 7: playlist();

            case 13: copyFile();
                    break;

            case 14: openFile();
                    break;

            case 15: System.exit(0); 
                    break;
        }
    }
}

public static void addMovie()
{


    String name,director;
    double filesize,duration;

    System.out.println("What is the Name of the Movie:");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the Director of the Movie:");
    director = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the Duration of the Movie in minutes:");
    filesize = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the Filesize of the Movie in mb:");
    duration = input.nextDouble();

    md.addMovie(name,director,filesize,duration);           
}

public static void editMovie()
{

    System.out.println("What is the name of the movie you wish to edit?");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please retype the information of the movie you wish to edit");

    System.out.println("What is the Name of the Movie:");
    String mname = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the Director of the Movie:");
    String director = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is the Duration of the Movie in minutes:");
    double filesize = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What is the Filesize of the Movie in mb:");
    double duration = input.nextDouble();

    md.edit(name,mname,director,filesize,duration);   
}

public static void directorList()
{
    System.out.println("What is the name of the director?");
    String director = input.nextLine();
    md.list(2,director,0);
}

public static void durationList()
{
    System.out.println("Duration the movies have to be under in Minutes");
    double duration = input.nextDouble();
    md.list(3,"",duration);
}

public static void playlist()
{   
    playlist[total] = new Playlist();

    total++;

    System.out.println("How many movies do you wish to save in this playlist?");
    num int = input.nextInt();

    storage = new Playlist();

    for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++)
    {
        System.out.println("Type in the next movie:").
        String name = nextLine;

        if(md.check(name)==1)
        {
            storage[i] = md.getMovie1(name);
        }   

        else if(md.check(name)==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Movie you typed does not exist");
            i--;
        }
    }

    playlistarray[total] = storage;

    if(total == playlist.length)
    {
        increaseResize();
    }
}

public static void increasseResize()
{
    Playlist[] replaylist;
    replaylist = new Playlist[playlist.length+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++)
    {
        replaylist[i] = playlist[i];
    }

    playlist = replaylist;
}

public static void copyFile()
{
    String fileName = "out.text";
    PrinterWriter outputStream = null;

    try
    {
        outputStream = new PrintWriter (fileName);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println ("error opening the file");
        System.exit (0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < md.total; i++)
    {
        outputStream.println(md.getName(i) + line);
        outputStream.println(md.getDirector(i) + line);
        outputStream.println(md.getFilesize(i) + line);
        outputStream.println(md.getDuration(i) + line);
    }

    outputStream.close();

}

public static void openFile()
{
    String fileName = "readMe";
    System.out.println ("The file " + fileName + "\ncontains the following lines:\n");
    Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (new File (fileName));

    while (inputStream.hasNextLine ())
    {
        if(inputStream.hasNextInt())
        {
            while(inputStream.hasNextInt())
            {
                System.out.print(inputStream.nextInt());
            }
        }
        else
        {
        String line = inputStream.nextLine ();
        System.out.println (line);
        }
    }
    inputStream.close ();
}

public static void showSelection()
{
    System.out.println("1.Add Movies");
    System.out.println("2.Show All Movies Currently Listed");
    System.out.println("3.Delete a Movie");
    System.out.println("4.Edit an Existing Movie");
    System.out.println("5.Show All Movies from certain Director");
    System.out.println("6.Show all Movies under a certain Duration");
    System.out.println("7.Create a Playlist");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("13.Save Current movie database to a file");
    System.out.println("14.Open a movie database from a file");
    System.out.println("15.End Program");
}
```

}

```
    public class Movie
    {
    private String name;
    private String director;
    private double filesize;
    private double duration;

    public Movie()
    {
        name = "";
        director = "";
        filesize = 0;
        duration = 0;
    }

    //setting the method name
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        name = name;
    }

    //getting the method name
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    //setting the method director 
    public void setDirector(String director)
    {
        director = director;
    }

    //getting the method director
    public String getDirector()
    {
        return director;
    }

    // setting the method filesize
    public void setFilesize(double filesize)
    {
        filesize = filesize;
    }

    //getting the method filesize
    public double getFilesize()
    {
        return filesize;
    }

    //setting the method duration
    public void setDuration(double duration)
    {
        duration = duration;
    }

    //getting the method duration
    public double getDuration()
    {
        return duration;
    }
```

}

```
    public class MovieDatabase
    {
    final private int MAX = 5;
    private Movie[] movies;
    private int total;

    public MovieDatabase()
    {
        movies = new Movie[MAX];
        total = 0;
    }

    public void addMovie(String newName, String newDirector, double newFileSize, double newDuration)
    {
        if(check(newName) == 0)
        {
            movies[total] = new Movie();
            setMovie(movies[total],newName,newDirector,newFileSize,newDuration);
            total++;

            if(total == movies.length)
            {
                increaseResize();
            }
        }

        else if(check(newName) == 1)
            System.out.println("Movie already exists");
    }

    private void setMovie(Movie m,String newName, String newDirector, double newFileSize, double newDuration)
    {
        m.setName(newName);
        m.setDirector(newDirector);
        m.setFilesize(newFileSize);
        m.setDuration(newDuration);
    }

    public int movieTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    public double check(String name)
    {
        if(total > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
            {
                if(movies[i].getName() == name)
                {   
                    return 1;
                }

                else 
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        else
            return 0;
    }

    public String getMovie1(String name)
    {
        int i = position(name);
        setMovie = movies[i].getName();
        return setMovie;
    }

    public getMovie(int i)
    {
        String nom = movies[i].getName();
        return nom;
    }

    public getDirector(int i)
    {
        String nom = movies[i].getDirector();
        return nom;
    }

    public getFilesize(int i)
    {
        String nom = movies[i].getFilesize();
        return nom;
    }

    public getDuration(int i)
    {
        String nom = movies[i].getDuration();
        return nom;
    }

    private void increaseResize()
    {
        Movie [] removie;
        removie = new Movie[movies.length+1];

        for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++)
        {
            removie[i] = movies[i];
        }

        movies = removie;
    }

    public void list(int n,String name,double number)
    {
        //display all Movies
        if(n == 1)
        {
            if(total>0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(movies[i].getName());
                }
            }

            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot Display Movies if you haven't saved any yet.");
            }
        }
        //Display all Movies under certain Director
        else if(n == 2)
        {
            if(total > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
                {
                    if(movies[i].getDirector() == name)
                    {
                        System.out.println(movies[i].getName());
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Either no Movies exist or their are no movies under that Directors name");
            }           
        }
        //Display all Movies under certain Durtation
        else if(n == 3)
        {
            if(total > 0)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
                {
                    if(movies[i].getDuration() == number)
                    {
                        System.out.println(movies[i].getName());
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.println("Either no Movies exist or their are no movies under that Directors name");
            }
        }   
    }


    public void edit(String name, String newName, String newDirector, double newFileSize, double newDuration)
    {
        int p;
        p = position(name);
        movies[p] = new Movie();


            for(int i = -2; i < total -1; i++)
            {
                if(p == -1)
                {
                    System.out.println("The Movie you wish to delete does not exist");
                }

                else if(i == p)
                {
                    setMovie(movies[p],newName,newDirector,newFileSize,newDuration);
                }

            }
    }


    public void delete(String name)
    {
        int p;
        p = position(name);
        if(p == -1)
        {
            System.out.println("The Movie you wish to delete does not exist");
        }

        else
        {
            for(int i = p; i < total -1; i++)
            {
                movies[i] = movies[i+1];
                total --;
            }
        }
    }

    private int position(String name)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < total; i++)
        {
            if(movies[i].getName() == name)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

}

```
    public class Playlist
    {
    final private int MAX = 4;
    final private int MAX_TIME = 1000;
    final private int MAX_SIZE = 20000;
    private Movie[] movies;
    private int total;


    public Playlist()
    {
        movies = new Movie[MAX]
    }


}
```

`

Comment: Are you asking how to create two dimensional array?

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of a beginner to coding, im not exactly sure what a two dimensional array is but what I am trying to do is. the storage object stores all the movies you input, and then I want to store the storage object into the playlist object. Can you do that using two dimensional arrays, or should I use an arraylist? i am very confused

Comment: Why not use a List (like ArrayList)? And will be good to see the rest of the code, values of that total. Storage[num] seems incorrect, and can't see the size, guess is Total.

Comment: @Daniel Ugh, first of all, you could use `==` in your `if` statements. A single `=` assign the value, two compare the values

Comment: @DanielKim if you are a beginner go for ArrayList.

Comment: @DanielKim Your setters won't work. When you type `name = name;` in your movie class, you don't set the attribute, you set the parameter. You must use `this.name = name;`.
Also, you're missing a break in your switch statement (unless that was the desired behavior).

Comment: A friend said that you don't have to put the this. but thank you since that part works now. ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Since you want a dinamic array of `Playlist` in your `Storage`, you can just use a `List<Playlist>`.

Something like:

```
List<Playlist> storage = new ArrayList<Playlist>();

System.out.println("How many movies do you wish to save in this playlist?");
num int = input.nextInt();
Playlist p = new Playlist();

for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++)
{
    System.out.println("Type in the next movie:").
    String name = nextLine;
    //Verifications
    if(md.check(name) == 1)
        storage[i] = md.getMovie1(name);
    else if(md.check(name) == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Movie you typed does not exist");
        i--;
    }
    //Add the movie to Playlist
    p.add(md.getMovie1(name);
}
storage.add(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, um the problem is that we are only allowed to make 4 classes, Movie,Moviedatabase,Playlist and Interface. would it help if I just post all my classes I have up to now

Comment: @DanielKim I just realized your code is **really** not compiling. You should probably read a tutorial on ArrayLists (and maybe on java first). For example, you wrote `Storage[num] = xxx`, but your variable has no name.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your MD class return something of type Storage

```
 public static void playlist()
 {   
  final List<Object> playlist = new ArrayList();

  final Scanner finput = new Scanner(System.in);
  String input;

  System.out.println("How many movies do you wish to save in this playlist?");

  int num = input.nextInt();

  // final List<Object> storage = Storage.getStorage();

  for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++)
  {
     System.out.println("Type in the next movie:").
     String name = finput.nextLine();

     if(md.check(name)==1)
     {
         playlist.add(md.getMovie1(name));
     }   

     else
     {
         System.out.println("Movie you typed does not exist");
         i--;
     }
  }

 }
```

if not where the `playlist.add()` is you can add `storage.get(name)`.

But without see more from your code, is only guessing.